# Issue Evaluating & Iterating A Regex in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, iteration

My objective is to converting my working Python script logic into an Excel VBA macro. Since I am not well versed in VBA, I am having a few issues with constructs that work in Python but not here. As background, my Python script reads a Word Doc, asks user input to create a pattern from premade variables containing regex snippets, performs the regex on the docx and returns those results into Excel cells. The following code is the problematic part of what I have so far with Excel VBA:

```
patterninput = InputBox("a1 = Title" & vbNewLine & "a2 = First Name" & vbNewLine & "a3 = Last Name" & vbNewLine & "b = Address" & vbNewLine & "c = Town, State Zip" & vbNewLine & "x = Line Omit", "Step #3: Enter Pattern")
            Dim x As String
            Dim a1 As String
            Dim a2 As String
            Dim a3 As String
            Dim b As String
            Dim c As String
            x = "(?:.+)\s+"
            a1 = "([\w\.]+)\s+"
            a2 = "(\w+)\s+"
            a3 = "(.+)[\s\n]+"
            b = "(\d+\s.+)[\s\n]+"
            c = "(.+)"
    pattern = keyword & "[\s\n]+" & Application.Evaluate(patterninput)

    Dim objMatches As MatchCollection

    With regEx
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = pattern
    End With

    Set objMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
    Dim row As Long
    Dim SubMatches As Variant
    row = .Rows.Count + 1
    For Each SubMatches In objMatches
        Cells(row, 1).Value = objMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
        Cells(row, 2).Value = objMatches(0).SubMatches(1)
        Cells(row, 3).Value = objMatches(0).SubMatches(2)
        Cells(row, 4).Value = objMatches(0).SubMatches(3)
        Cells(row, 5).Value = objMatches(0).SubMatches(4)
        row = row + 1
    Next
```

My first issue is that I cannot seem to evaluate the patterninput, like how eval() works in Python, so that trips an error. Is there a way I can evaluate and concatenate the users input all while assigning to the pattern variable the appropriate snippets?

If I omit this piece and hard code a pattern for demo purposes, I run into the second, more important problem. I want the regex to find a match and then take each submatch and put it into 5 separate columns in the same row (I want this to start on the max row + 1; basically the first unwritten row). Once this is done, I want it to move onto the next match, perform the same thing but on the next row (hence the row = row + 1 because VBA apparently can't do row += 1). However, the way it works right now, it does the first two columns correctly, but then throws the rest of the text (and viable matches) into the third column and finishes. I need it to iterate through, but I cannot seem to get this to work. The following is the demo text I am using where "Sincerely" is the keyword:

```
Dear Sir,

Hello

Sincerely,

Mr. Thomas Dahlmer
46 Alpine Street
Evanston, Il 60201

Dear Sir,

Hello

Sincerely,

Mr. Robert Thomas
1104 Madison Avenue
New York, NY 10021
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as hopefully I can learn from this and become better acquainted with Excel VBA. Thank you!

Comment: My impression is that you're trying to do too much with too few lines of code. Granted that Python (and Ruby and others) have rather powerful parsing abilities for mapping tokens into variables, but VBA is older and far less efficient. I would suggest a function that takes your input line and parses it, then returns all required variables to `ByRef` function parameters. Wrap this in a loop so you can increment your destination row counter to appropriately place the results on your worksheet.

Comment: Based on your limited examples, you might be better off using Instr looking for vbLF & "Sincerely," & vbCRLF & vbCRLF. Save the regex for parsing the elements of the contact information after you retrieve the block of information.

Comment: @PeterT I feel like there has to be a solution though as it "works," I just can't get it to move on to the next full match ( I'm assuming it is because it jumbles up on the third submatch). It is the oddest thing. It is almost as if it can't understand the pattern of "Sincerely,[\s\n]+([\w\.]+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.+)[\s\n]+(\d+\s.+)[\s\n]+(.+)" because on regex checkers, it is correct.

Comment: @Jeeped How would one go about this? How would it know to apply this pattern of functions to the next "letter" if you will? That's why I chose to use regexs, as I can save matches. Does your way work only on one instance of "Sincerely,"?

Comment: No, it works because every letter has a *Sincerely,* in it. I assumed that you wanted to parse out the contact information and that is easily located as the string block after *Sincerely,*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get the body text of your letters into my `str` variable; I've just put the sample text into A2 (actually, A2:A17 merged) for demonstration purposes. There are plenty of examples on getting a text file into a string variable on this site.

This uses Instr and Split to avoid using a regex pattern. TBPH, I'm just not that good at multi-line, global regex patterns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqreqwq()
    Dim b As Long, e As Long
    Dim str As String, sal As String, con As String
    Dim info As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        ReDim info(4)
        sal = "sincerely," & vbLf & vbLf
        str = Replace(.Cells(2, "A").Value2, vbCrLf, vbLf) & vbLf & vbLf

        b = InStr(1, str, sal, vbTextCompare)
        Do While CBool(b)
            b = b + Len(sal)
            e = InStr(b, str, vbLf & vbLf, vbTextCompare)
            'b = InStr(e + 2, str, sal, vbTextCompare)

            con = Mid(str, b, e - b)
            info = Split(con, vbLf)
            ReDim Preserve info(4)
            info(3) = Split(info(2), Chr(44) & Chr(32))(1)
            info(2) = Split(info(2), Chr(44) & Chr(32))(0)
            info(4) = Split(info(3), Chr(32))(1)
            info(3) = Split(info(3), Chr(32))(0)
            .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 5) = info

            b = InStr(e, str, sal, vbTextCompare)
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

I've left the zip codes as text-that-looks-like-a-number. Typically, I convert the etxt to a number and use a custom number format like `[>99999]00000-0000;00000;[red]@` that shows zips-as-true-numbers while allowing zips and zip+4's. Any value that refuses to become a true number is displayed in a red font to let you know of the failed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! While I figured out that my initial problem is due to VBScript's rather simple regex abilities, this is a good workaround for what I am trying to do. I will try to implement it as well!